# Remove a JSON attribute using button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, arrays, json, asp.net-mvc-4

If I have json Object Say.

```
<script>
$(function () {
    var tr;
    var obj = [{ obj1: { "name": "v1", nestobj: [{ "value": "10" }, { "value": "20" }, { "value": "30" }] } }];

    obj.push({ obj1: { "name": "v2", nestobj: [{ "value": "abc" }, { "value": "xyz" }] } });

    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        tr = $("<tr id='a3'/>");
        $('p').css('border-top', '5px');
        $('p').css('border-color', 'black');

        tr.append("<td id='a2'>" + obj[i].obj1.name + "</td>")
        $('tbody').append(tr);

        for (var j = 0; j < obj[i].obj1.nestobj.length; j++) {

            tr.append("<p>" + obj[i].obj1.nestobj[j].value + "<input type='button' value='remove value' style='color:blue;' onclick=''></p>")
            $('tbody').append(tr);
        }                    
    }   
});
```

can I remove 'nestobj' using button onclick function so it becomes:

Comment: What you have is a JavaScript array containing objects. There is no JSON here.

Comment: yap there is json @felix kling

Comment: No, there is not. JSON is a textual data format, like XML, YAML or CSV. You have JavaScript code. Please read [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2904131/218196) to learn more about the difference. Either way, your question is unclear. I can't spot the difference between the existing objects and the desired result. Do you just want to delete a property of an object? Or do you want to remove an element from an array?

Comment: thanks i will clear that

Comment: how to delete 'nestobj' ' value ' using button onclick function

Answer (score 0):

In your button on-click event put this below

delete obj["nestobj"];